# Uncheck a checkbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have trouble to create a script that deselect a chebock when the other on the same line is selected

```js
        function uncheck1(){
            document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("select").disabled = true;
        }
        function uncheck2(){
            document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("check2").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("select").disabled = false;
        }
```

```html
    <form name="form" action="action.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Carrizo J." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Carrizo J.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check1" onclick="uncheck1()" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check2" onclick="uncheck2()" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select" name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Handanovic S." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Handanovic S.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check1" onclick="uncheck1()" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check2" onclick="uncheck2()" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select" name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

[image: This is the final result]

As well as, obviusly, it works only the first line.
If I check the right one, the left one is unchecked and the select is enabled.
Then if I check the left one, the right one is unchecked and select is disabled.

Is there a way to be able to do the same things to other 24 lines, without having to write 2 functions for each?

Comment: Why not use a radio input instead?

Comment: A set of radio buttons with the same name will do exactly what you are asking AND be understood by everyone. ALSO IDs need to be unique

Comment: Radio buttons make sense...unless it's homework?

Comment: @James: there's no rule against helping with homework assignments, but if it *is* a homework assignment then the OP would (ideally) specify that, along with any arbitrary constraints (such as using check-boxes rather than radios), and even in that situation, with that constraint, check-boxes are the wrong choice, and I'd expect any student given that assignment to point out the UI, along with the functional, problems.

Comment: It's not an homework, it's for a game called fantacalcio, the players list is my team.
I want to set regular player (0) and bench player (1) .
Then if a player is set to 1, i want to choose the order on the bench.
Look at this page http://primoverofantacalcio.altervista.org/prova.php
Sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```js
window.onload = function() { // when page loaded
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='titolare[]']");
  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) { // assign to each checkbox
    checks[i].onclick = function() {
      var row = this.parentElement.parentElement, // the TR
      checks = row.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), // All checkboxes
        sel = row.querySelector("select"); // the select in the row
      sel.disabled = this.value == "0"; // whatever you clicked
      checks[0].checked = this.value == "0";
      checks[1].checked = this.value == "1";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="action.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Carrizo J." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Carrizo J.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select" name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Handanovic S." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Handanovic S.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select" name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: this.value is the correct thing to use - on click will always be checked

Comment: Using radio does not allow me to make a choice for every player but only for the last.
I want to set titolare[] 0 or 1 for every player, and if 1, enable select to choose the order.

Comment: If can help, here is the complete page on my website http://primoverofantacalcio.altervista.org/prova.php

Comment: My code works now - it does not look at initial state. If you need that, let me know

Comment: If I want to send a 0, when select is disabled what should I do?
Because when I click submit, array ordine[] it contains only the values of the select enabled, and then the indexes don't match those of the other array

Comment: Add a hidden field or option 0 and force option 0 instead of disabling

Comment: Or better, test the checkbox on the server. If check1, ignore select

Comment: Pps: I removed the inline onclick

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the checkboxes with radio buttons but need to name each pair separately, e.g. using the name in the label. You can keep the existing scheme of checkboxes if you are sure the script will run on the client.

One approach is to dynamically add the click listeners and at the same time, add an index to each checkbox using a *data-* attribute. When a checkbox with an even index is clicked, uncheck the next odd one. If one with an odd index is clicked, uncheck the previous even one.

A similar scheme can be used for the selects, except you don't need a *data-* attribute as long as there are only selects matched to checkbox pairs. I've slimmed down the HTML a bit…

E.g.

```js
function updateSelect(){
  var idx = this.dataset.index;

  // Uncheck related checkbox. If this one's index
  // is even, uncheck next, otherwise previous
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkboxes[idx % 2? idx - 1 : +idx +1 ].checked = false;

  // Get the select elements
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

  // Find related select based on checkbox index
  var selIdx = Math.floor(idx/2);

  // Disable based on whether related checkbox index is odd or even
  selects[selIdx].disabled = !(idx%2);
} 

window.onload = function(){
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  [].forEach.call(checkboxes,function(cb, idx) {
    cb.addEventListener('click', updateSelect, false);

    // Add in index to each checkbox so it's easy to find the previous or next
    cb.dataset.index = idx;    
  })
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="Carrizo J." name="player[]">
      <td><label>Carrizo J.</label>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1">
      <td><select name="ordine[]" disabled>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
          </select>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="Handanovic S." name="player[]">
      <td><label>Handanovic S.</label>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="0" checked>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="titolare[]" value="1">
      <td><select name="ordine[]" disabled>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
          </select>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note that NodeLists are now iterable, so you in some hosts instead of:

```
[].forEach.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox, index){...})
```

you could do:

```
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, index){...})
```

But support may be lacking in many browsers in use (for the time being).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is pretty much what you're looking for, and I think the changes are self-explanatory:

```js
function checkChange(elem) {
  var elemRoot = elem.parentNode.parentNode;
  elemRoot.querySelectorAll("select[name='ordine[]']")[0].disabled = !elemRoot.getElementsByClassName('memberRadio2')[0].checked;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="action.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Carrizo J." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="titolare1">Carrizo J.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="checkChange(this)" type="radio" name="titolare1" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="checkChange(this)" type="radio" name="titolare1" value="1" class="memberRadio2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="Handanovic S." name="player[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="titolare2">Handanovic S.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="checkChange(this)" type="radio" name="titolare2" value="0" checked="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="checkChange(this)" type="radio" name="titolare2" value="1" class="memberRadio2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ordine[]" disabled>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note: You will need to change the logic on the server side to make use of the multiple radio values (indexed using separate names).